# How to delete elements from str

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I've created a string out of array(from BD) and string looks badly:

```
a:1:{i:0;a:7:{s:2:"id";s:1:"1";s:5:"title";s:39:"shock absorber ms 290, 310, 390";s:11:"description";s:32:"size - 8х22х29 mm.";s:3:"img";s:1:"1";s:5:"price";s:4:"0.9$";s:8:"category";s:38:"Details";s:5:"brand";s:5:"Stihl";}}
```

How can I delete everything but shock absorber ms 290, 310, 390. Mind that it's a order letter so substr won't help 'cause letter will have a lot more products with different number of symbols

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$tel = $_POST['tel'];
$g = $_SESSION['cart_list'];
$c = serialize($g);

$title = "order";
$body = "
<h2>New order</h2>
<b>Name:</b> $name<br>
<b>Tel:</b> $tel<br><br>
<b>Cart:</b>$c<br>
";
```

Comment: You want to manipulate it while it's an array, then encode it.  `json_encode` is a better choice.

Comment: You serialise `$_SESSION['cart_list'];` Why? What does it look like before you do that

Comment: And if it actually generates that serialized string, you have a multibyte char set issue there as well, because this `s:32:"size - 8х22х29 mm."` is not a 32 byte long string

Comment: $_SESSION['cart_list']; is products in cart during current session. json_encode maybe is better but some of my letters are cyrillic and I get something like: \u0410\u043c\u043e\ in mail.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$tel = $_POST['tel'];
$g = $_SESSION['cart_list'];
$c = serialize(array_map(function($e){return $e['title'];}, $g));
```

Thanks for your trying to help me!